# scipy fit for t distribution seems broken for bi-modal data

Tags: statistics

I am using the scipy.stats.t.fit function, and I am surprised by the results. If I fit on some bimodal data, say

```
data=[1,1,1,1,5,5]
```

I get

```
df=0.39126249808550329
loc=1.0
scale=5.7172845190830792e-21
```

That is, the scale is effectively zero, and I will never be able to sample anything near 5, just the more frequent data point 1.

I guess you really can't fit on data that is too different from a t-distribution - but is scipy really giving the best t dist fit to the data? I would think that if I compute a sample mean and variance myself, i.e,

```
df = 5
loc = 2.33
scale = 1.88
```

That I'd have a better fit, although I haven't computed the likelihood of sampling `[1,1,1,5,5]` from these two t distributinos.

Answer (score 1):

The t-test has many assumptions. That dataset violates several of them:

- Data should be sufficiently large (>30 independent points)
- Data should be approximately normally distributed

Given that the assumptions are violated, you can **not** expect to valid results.